# I clean installed 20.04 LTS but now I have no network

Tags: networking, 20.04

I was running 16.04 LTS (32 bit)
And decided to upgrade to 20.04 LTS. I removed the drive with 16.04 on it and installed a new SSD. I installed via DVD from downloaded iso. Once it is installed and I reboot there is no network. The ethernet controller does not show under network settings. 
If I run sudo lshw -C network I get:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
     description: Ethernet controller
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
     version: 3
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff memory:fd400000-fd41ffff
```

The cable is plugged in and there are lights on both the adapter on the PC and the router.
I have tried reinstalling but same issue. It worked fine with 16.04 and the only things different are the new SSD and the new OS.
I am not very familiar with linux - just a user.
Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_usb_audio         258048  1
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_amd                98304  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
radeon               1474560  10
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
ttm                   106496  1 radeon
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
wmi_bmof               16384  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 radeon
serio_raw              20480  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
k10temp                16384  0
snd                    90112  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  6 drm_kms_helper,radeon,ttm
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  1 uas
hid_logitech_hidpp     40960  0
hid_logitech_dj        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   131072  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
pata_acpi              16384  0
pata_jmicron           16384  0
firewire_ohci          40960  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
realtek                24576  0
ahci                   40960  2
pata_atiixp            16384  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
floppy                 81920  0

 $ dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816|error|fail'
[    0.193357] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.193357] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.206387] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206392] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206395] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206398] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206407] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206410] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206413] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206415] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206424] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206426] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206429] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206432] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206440] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206443] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206446] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206449] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206457] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206460] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206463] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206466] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206474] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206477] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206480] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206483] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206491] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206494] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206497] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206500] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206508] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206511] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206514] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206516] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206525] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206528] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206530] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206533] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206541] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206544] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206547] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.206550] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.226588] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.226589] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.226589] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.226602] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.248324] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.249337] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.249341] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    0.873227] i8042: Failed to disable AUX port, but continuing anyway... Is this a SiS?
[    1.129168] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.129307] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.136569] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.136850] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    1.243699] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.246892] libphy: r8169: probed
[    1.246894] r8169 0000:03:00.0: realtek.ko not loaded, maybe it needs to be added to initramfs?
[    1.272769] r8169: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -49
[    3.653707] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    5.357098] audit: type=1400 audit(1590039568.703:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=595 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.357579] audit: type=1400 audit(1590039568.703:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=595 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   98.557314] audit: type=1107 audit(1590039661.903:1562): pid=674 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.13" pid=3278 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=675 peer_label="unconfined"
[12157.551604] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[12157.554165] libphy: r8169: probed
[12157.554167] r8169 0000:03:00.0: realtek.ko not loaded, maybe it needs to be added to initramfs?
[12157.572403] r8169: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -49
[13125.601531] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 264544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13125.601542] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 44, lost async page write
[13125.601562] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 6555656 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[13125.601567] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 786433, lost async page write
[13125.872264] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[13202.988262] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK


$ ifconfig -a

Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools

$ sudo apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package net-tools
```

Comment: `apt-cache show r8168-dkms` possibly the issue. If r8168-dkms is installed, remove it. If not, try to install it. (https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:10ec-8168-10ec-0123)

Comment: This is extremely frustrating for a dummy. Why can't I just install the OS and it work?? I downloaded r8168-8.048.02.tar.bz2, which I assume is what you mean by r8168-dkms, and followed the instructions in the readme file. When I try to run ./autorun.sh I get ./autorun.sh:30 make: not found. After some searching on the net I find a suggestion to run sudo apt-get install build-essential. I get the error Unable to locate package build-essential. I try sudo apt-get install --reinstall make. I get the error Package make is not available. Now I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: I'll add more detail in an answer - will get too messy for comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The r8168 driver is included in the Ubuntu repositories so you don't need to compile it yourself, so first, try this:

```
sudo rmmod r8169 r8168
sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms
sudo modprobe r8169
dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816'
ifconfig -a
```

If there were no errors reported by the modprobe or found in dmesg then you should see an ethernet device in the ifconfig output (in addition to the lo device).

If not, try the r8168 driver:

```
sudo rmmod r8169
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
sudo modprobe r8168
dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816'
ifconfig -a
```

If you still get no ethernet device, add the output of:

```
find /lib -name r816\*
lsmod
dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816|error|fail'
ifconfig -a
```

to the original question.

Comment: Wait - how stupid of me. You don't have any network at all on this machine, do you? Without a network `apt-get install` is not going to work unless the package is on the DVD and /etc/apt/sources.list is configured to use it. You may need to go to download the packages manually on another system. I'll add a step for that.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I tried some of the above and this is what I got:

Comment: $ sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r8168-dkms
$ sudo modprobe r8169
cont.....

Comment: $ dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816'
[    0.193357] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.193357] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.226588] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.226589] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.226589] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.226602] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.248324] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.249337] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.249341] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    1.129168] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
cont...

Comment: [    1.129307] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.136569] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.243699] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.246892] libphy: r8169: probed
[    1.246894] r8169 0000:03:00.0: realtek.ko not loaded, maybe it needs to be added to initramfs?
[    1.272769] r8169: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -49
[    5.357098] audit: type=1400 audit(1590039568.703:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=595 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: [    5.357579] audit: type=1400 audit(1590039568.703:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=595 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   98.557314] audit: type=1107 audit(1590039661.903:1562): pid=674 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.13" pid=3278 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=675 peer_label="unconfined"

Comment: [12157.551604] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[12157.554165] libphy: r8169: probed
[12157.554167] r8169 0000:03:00.0: realtek.ko not loaded, maybe it needs to be added to initramfs?
[12157.572403] r8169: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -49
$ ifconfig -a

Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools

$ sudo apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package net-tools
$ sudo rmmod r8169

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r8168-dkms

Comment: AH - that looks like a known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1876593. Still reading it ....

Comment: Sounds like they are saying it is a motherboard BIOS bug. Is this you motherboard? https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-890GPA-UD3H-rev-20/support#support-dl-bios

Comment: Yes, that is my motherboard. I have updated the BIOS and turned on the LAN Boot option as suggested in the bug report and now it is working. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out it was a known issue with the motherboard:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1876593

Problem resolved by upgrading BIOS to latest and turning on LAN Boot option as suggested in the bug report. Thanks to Wayne Vosberg.

Answer (score 0):

When i had no internet on Realtek 8168/8169, this worked to fix it:

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
reboot
```

Comment: Please be a little careful with 'Copy and Paste' answers on AU...